# Implementation of version control for VisualFiles

Tags: version-control

I am researching development in VisualFiles.

How can I use version control on the files(scripts) I have changed?

My solution so far:

**Setup:**
Create a folder structure within the repository according to my applications.

**Update process**

1. I will modify a file in visual files
2. I will then manually have to update file in a repository
3. Commit the changes against a work item

Is there a better way of introducing version control for VisualFiles. Because to me this feels like not an ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty much the only solution at the moment. The team I am in does something similar but only really for major versions, in minor changes we will feature-switch within the code and leave the old edits inline with dates and initials

The platform provider (LexisNexis) have determined changess to code editor functionality as "likely to implement". This may or may not include version control, that is not yet known, if it does it will be in released v4.1+. There are no other tools available to achieve your aim within the platform. Ask your account manager for access to the ideas portal and you can see when their dev team commit to enhancements such as this.

As source/version control is a long standing issue, any devs using the platform have always had to find workarounds as per your suggestion. The providers are highly unlikely to push any version control functionality with backwards compatability pre v4.